# MySQL - convert varbinary to XML file

Tags: php, xml, sharepoint, varbinary

I am programming a **PHP** intranet and have problems with extracting of data from older system. It was created with **Sharepoint** and **MSSQL**. It stores the data terribly unclean.
I found the desired data searching by keyword only by accident with help of HeidiSQL (db management tool). Its fulltext filter is searching also in varbinary columns and one time it converted the **varbinary** content **to** meaningful **xml** data (I saw header + 50 next letters), but only for a second, then it disappeared back to the original value.

I moved data from SQLserver to MySQL via CSV export, so I can work with PHP.

The varbinary contains this value:

```
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
```

How can I convert it back to meaningful XML?  I tried these PHP functions: `hexdec()`, `base64_encode()`, `base64_decode()` - but none is working.

There is 10.000 rows there... Please help me :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are retrieving data from SharePoint you should never hit the SQL database, use the API's instead.

Comment: Sorry, i dont have the access to Sharepoint. I only have the database, which i imported to MS SQLexpress 2008. I found software SSMSBoost for SSMS 2008 and it can visualise the varbinary to text, but only for single item in time. So i am looking for solution which can store 10000 files and not doing it manually.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3 and there is no hex2bin, so i found an alternative on PHP manual site:
    if ( !function_exists( 'hex2bin' ) ) {
    function hex2bin( $str ) {
        $sbin = "";
        $len = strlen( $str );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 2 ) {
            $sbin .= pack( "H*", substr( $str, $i, 2 ) );
        }

        return $sbin;
    }
}

Comment: Did you got it solved? I'm looking for similar issue

Answer (score 1):

This works well also in PHP <5.4, thank you for your time:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'hex2bin' ) ) {
    function hex2bin( $str ) {
        $sbin = "";
        $len = strlen( $str );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 2 ) {
            $sbin .= pack( "H*", substr( $str, $i, 2 ) );
        }

        return $sbin;
    }
}
```